# DataGrid displaying the wrong dateformat

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid

I'm displaying some information about case which already exist in a `DataGrid`.

In my `MS Access` database all the date are stored in a `DateTime` format and looks like this : dd/MM/yyyy.

The problem is that when displayed on the `DataGrid` when the program runs, the format change to MM/dd/yyyy.

The thing that makes me lost is that when I display in a `MessageBox` the content of the concerned cells just before assign the `DataTable` to the `DataGrid` I've got the right format (dd/MM/yyyy).

I've tried to change the `DateTimeMode` but the same format is displayed.

Someone got any tips who to fix this problem ? I give you the code below :

DataTable temp = dt.Clone();

```
            temp = (from nardin in dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct()
                    where nardin["NUMERO CLIENT"].ToString() == _centerID.ToString()
                    select nardin).CopyToDataTable();





            RemoveDuplicates(temp, "NUMERO DOSSIER");


            foreach (DataRow row in temp.Rows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(row["DATE INTERVENTION"].ToString()); //this gives me the DateTime format i'd like to display
            }

            existingCase.ItemsSource = temp.AsDataView(); //once assigned to the DataGrid the DateTime format is not the same as above
```

Actually the DataGrid is declared like this in the xaml file :

```
   <DataGrid  SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBI, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"   Margin="0,167,12,167" Name="existingBI"  Width="588" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="resultDataGridBI_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

I'm binding the DataTable with: `existingCase.ItemsSource = temp.AsDataView();`

In advance, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `Startup` event handle in `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="DataGridAddRows.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup" ... />
```

In `App.xaml.cs` add this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

Now, the date should be displayed depending on the current culture.

**`Note:`** `StringFormat` suitable *only* for display the date. If you want to edit a cell with a date, such as the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, entering data in a way `dd/MM/yyyy`, the system will be expected format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so the error will appear as a red `Border`.

Comment: Okay, it works perfectly with my thread setting the datetime culture !

Thanks for this !

Answer (score 0):

Without displaying your code for the column in the `DataGrid` that displays the `DateTime` object, it is hard to answer, but I will assume that you are binding the value. To set a string format on the binding, you would do something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, 
            StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I quoted the dg declaration. 

I tried to add your solution but the same result.